# select the records with the highest amount

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi trying to get records from a db table
according to the highest percentage of game played

```
 user_id| game         | CompletePercentage
----------------------------------
 1      | name1        | 90
 2      | name2        | 67
 3      | name4        | 100
 4      | name1        | 50
 1      | name4        | 80
 1      | name3        | 70
 1      | name1        | 60
 2      | name2        | 70
 1      | name1        | 50
```

So if I want to get the records for user_id 1 for all games played but only highest

```
user_id | game         | highestPercent
----------------------------------
 1      | name1        | 90
 1      | name4        | 80
 1      | name3        | 70
```

I've been trying

```
SELECT user_id, game , MAX(CompletePercentage) AS highestPercent 
FROM completedscenarios 
GROUP BY game 
HAVING user_id=1
```

but with only limited success.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user_id, game, CompletePercentage as highestPercentage
FROM completedscenarios 
WHERE user_id = 1 
ORDER BY CompletePercentage DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Order by the percentage, `MAX` only gives the one maximum value.  Since you want more than one record order by the column that you want and use `LIMIT` to trim the set.

Comment: thanks for this answer, it was the clearest however, it returned too many duplicate records, because it's possible to have many records at 100, what worked in the end was
 
`SELECT user_id, ScenarioName, CompletePercentage AS highestPercentage
FROM completedscenarios
WHERE user_id =1
**GROUP BY ScenarioName**
ORDER BY CompletePercentage DESC`
thanks again

Comment: hi spoke to soon it doesn't return the highest number, actually returns the lowest

Answer (score 2):

You can try a self join like this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27977e/9):

Just to expand on some other ways you can use this, I've updated the original fiddle to [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be68a/3). Also, I added an extra datapoint for user 4 to show what happened with duplicates.

- To get the data for one user (original query):

```sql
SELECT c1.*
FROM completedscenarios c1
  LEFT JOIN completedscenarios c2 
    ON c1.user_id = c2.user_id 
      AND c1.game = c2.game 
      AND c1.CompletePercentage < c2.completePercentage
WHERE c1.user_id = 1 and c2.user_id is null;
```

- To get all users and their best scores per game

```sql
SELECT c1.user_id, c1.game, c1.CompletePercentage
FROM completedscenarios c1
  LEFT JOIN completedscenarios c2 ON c1.user_id = c2.user_id 
    AND c1.game = c2.game 
    AND c1.CompletePercentage < c2.completePercentage
WHERE c2.user_id is null
ORDER BY c1.user_id, c1.CompletePercentage;
```

- To get all games and the highest percentages no matter what user

```sql
SELECT c1.game, c1.user_id, c1.CompletePercentage
FROM completedscenarios c1
  LEFT JOIN completedscenarios c2 ON c1.game = c2.game 
    AND c1.CompletePercentage < c2.completePercentage
WHERE c2.game is null
ORDER BY c1.game, c1.CompletePercentage;
```

- To get users and their best overall game

```sql
SELECT c1.user_id, c1.game, c1.CompletePercentage
FROM completedscenarios c1
  LEFT JOIN completedscenarios c2 ON c1.user_id = c2.user_id 
    AND c1.CompletePercentage < c2.completePercentage
WHERE c2.user_id is null
ORDER BY c1.user_id, c1.CompletePercentage;
```

- And here is a copy of the results

```sql
USER_ID | GAME  | COMPLETEPERCENTAGE
------------------------------------
1       | name1 | 90
1       | name4 | 80
1       | name3 | 70
```

```
USER_ID | GAME  | COMPLETEPERCENTAGE
------------------------------------
1       | name3 | 70
1       | name4 | 80
1       | name1 | 90
2       | name2 | 70
3       | name4 | 100
4       | name1 | 50
4       | name2 | 70
```

```
GAME  | USER_ID | COMPLETEPERCENTAGE
------------------------------------
name1 | 1       | 90
name2 | 2       | 70
name2 | 4       | 70
name3 | 1       | 70
name4 | 3       | 100
```

```
USER_ID | GAME  | COMPLETEPERCENTAGE
------------------------------------
1       | name1 | 90
2       | name2 | 70
3       | name4 | 100
4       | name2 | 70
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  user_id,
        game,
        MAX(CompletePercentage) AS highestPercent
  FROM completedscenarios
  GROUP BY user_id, game
  WHERE user_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT user_id, game,CompletePercentage as highestPercent 
 FROM completedscenarios 
 WHERE user_id=1 
 ORDER BY highestPercent DESC
 Limit 5`
```

Comment: as a side note it may be an idea to normalise your completedscenarios table.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the user_id and then the game, with a max(percentage)

```
select user_id, game,max(completepercentage) from @table
where user_id = 1
group by user_id,game
```

You can then add ordering if you like, but the above gives the desired result

Comment: Thanks, this works and is simple enough for me to understand and implement with my limited knowledge of SQL

Answer (score 0):

And this query will help you to get the game with the highest percentage per user

```
SELECT g.user_id, g.game, g.CompletePercentage FROM 
games g 
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT user_id, game, CompletePercentage FROM games
 ORDER BY CompletePercentage DESC
) j ON g.user_id = j.user_id 
GROUP BY g.user_id
```

It's a well known method of doing ordering before grouping.